# Sparkline Gantt Chart selecting earliest date from column and latest from another columns when i want individual dates to be displayed

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gantt-chart, sparklines

I am struggling with a Gantt chart/ sparkline distinguishing unique trade numbers and dates as it aggregates all the inputted data and illustrates either the earliest date and latest date so all the lines are the same. I would like these to be individual based on "Trade numbers"
The information should show the delivery schedule in the Gantt chart, whether it's buy or sell distinguished by 2 colours.
Start date (Trade Date)
End Date (Due Date)

The formula I have is:
`=if(Countif(Query(filter(Consolidated_TradeTrack!$A$2:$G, ((Consolidated_TradeTrack!$B$2>=F$8)*(Consolidated_TradeTrack!$A$2<=F$8))), "Select Col5 Where Col5 = '"&$D9&"'"),$D9)>0, SPARKLINE(Consolidated_TradeTrack!$F$2:G$2,{"charttype","bar";"max",max(2);"color1",switch($D9,"Buy","#7E3F8F","Sell","#FE7F2D")})," ")`

Formatted differently:

```
=if(
  Countif(
    Query(
      filter(
        Consolidated_TradeTrack!$A$2:$G,
        (Consolidated_TradeTrack!$B$2>=F$8)*(Consolidated_TradeTrack!$A$2<=F$8)
      ), 
      "Select Col5 Where Col5 = '"&$D9&"'"),
    $D9
  )>0,
  SPARKLINE(
    Consolidated_TradeTrack!$F$2:G$2,
    {
      "charttype","bar";
      "max",max(2);
      "color1",switch($D9,"Buy","#7E3F8F","Sell","#FE7F2D")
    }
  ),
  " "
)
```

[image]
[image]
Info is sources from a tab called "Consolidated_TradeTrack"
Which looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, your objective is to accomplish the following behavior:

[image]

where the cell corresponding to that **Date** and **Trade Number** is colored with the respective buy/sell color if the date falls between **Trade Date** and **Due Date**.

This can certainly be accomplished with the `SPARKLINE` function, however, bear in mind that the `SPARKLINE` function will create a chart (you can read the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289)). I presume that that is not what you want, as you would prefer the actual cells to be colored in.

That can be achieved with some **conditional formatting** (you can read the documentation about it [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413)). In my example (int the `G2` cell, the first of the Gantt Chart) I have set up two conditions; both with a `G2:Q4` range, with the *Format cells if* in `Custom formula is:` and with the following formulas:

```
=AND(G$1>=$A2,G$1<=$B2,$E2="Buy")
```

and

```
=AND(G$1>=$A2,G$1<=$B2,$E2="Sell")
```

Of course, you can extend the range of the conditional and modify the colors of each condition.